# angularjs unit testing unable to inject a service

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a really simple service:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('sapphire.orders').service('deliveryDatesService', service);

function service() {
    return {
        clearAddressReason: clearAddressReason,
        getMinDate: getMinDate
    };

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////

    function clearAddressReason(model, dateReasons, reasons) {
        if (model.manualAddress) {
            model.overrideDates = true;
            reasons.date = dateReasons.filter(function (item) {
                return item.value === 'D4';
            })[0];
        } else {
            reasons.address = null;
            if (!reasons.date || reasons.date.value === 'D4') {
                reasons.date = null;
                model.overrideDates = false;
            }
        }
    };

    function getMinDate(model) {
        var now = new Date();

        // If we are not overriding dates, set to today
        if (!model.overrideDates) return now;

        // If dates are overriden, then the min date is today + daysToDispatch
        return new Date(now.setDate(now.getDate() + model.daysToDispatch));
    };
};
```

It has no dependencies, so I want to test the methods.
So I have tried to create a spec like this:

```
'use strict';

describe('Service: deliveryDatesService', function () {
    beforeEach(module('sapphire.orders'));

    var service,
        reasons,
        dateReasons;

    beforeEach(inject(function (deliveryDatesService) {
        console.log(deliveryDatesService);
        service = deliveryDatesService;
        reasons = {};
        dateReasons = [{ value: 'D4' }];
    }));

    it('can create an instance of the service', function () {
        expect(service).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('if manual delivery address is true, then override dates should be true', function () {
        var model = { manualDeliveryDate: true };
        service.clearAddressReason(model, dateReasons, reasons);
        expect(model.overrideDates).toBe(true);
    });

    it('if manual delivery address is false, then override dates should be false', function () {
        var model = { manualDeliveryDate: false };
        service.clearAddressReason(model, dateReasons, reasons);
        expect(model.overrideDates).toBe(false);
    });

    it('minimum date cannot be less than today', function () {
        var model = { };
        var minDate = service.getMinDate(model);
        var now = new Date();
        expect(minDate).toBeGreaterThan(now);
    });
});
```

But my service is always undefined. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong please?

---

***Update***

So, it turns out this is to do with one or more services interfering somehow.
In my **karma.conf.js** I had declared all my bower applications and then this:

```
'src/app/app.module.js',
'src/app/**/*module.js',
'src/app/**/*constants.js',
'src/app/**/*service.js',
'src/app/**/*routes.js',
'src/app/**/*.js',
'test/spec/**/*.js'
```

I created a test service in the root of my scripts directory and then created a spec file to see if it was created. It moaned at me about a reference error in a file that was not related at all. It moaned about this bit of code:

```
angular.module('sapphire.core').factory('options', service);

function service($rootScope) {
    return {
        get: get,
        save: save
    };

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////

    function get() {
        if (Modernizr.localstorage) {
            var storageData = angular.fromJson(localStorage.options);
            if (storageData) {
                return angular.fromJson(storageData);
            }
        }

        return {
            background: {
                enabled: true,
                enableSnow: true,
                opacity: 0.6
            }
        };
    };

    function save(options) {
        if (Modernizr.localstorage) {
            localStorage.options = angular.toJson(options);
            $rootScope.$options = get();
        }
    };
};
```

stating that Modernizr is not defined.
I changed the code to this:

```
angular.module('sapphire.core').factory('options', service);

function service($rootScope) {
    return {
        get: get,
        save: save
    };

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////

    function get() {
        if (typeof Modernizr == 'object' && Modernizr.localstorage) {
            var storageData = angular.fromJson(localStorage.options);
            if (storageData) {
                return angular.fromJson(storageData);
            }
        }

        return {
            background: {
                enabled: true,
                enableSnow: true,
                opacity: 0.6
            }
        };
    };

    function save(options) {
        if (typeof Modernizr == 'object' && Modernizr.localstorage) {
            localStorage.options = angular.toJson(options);
            $rootScope.$options = get();
        }
    };
};
```

and it started working. But my other test was not.
So I changed my references in **karma.conf.js** to this:

```
'src/app/app.module.js',
'src/app/orders/orders.module.js',
'src/app/orders/shared/*.js',
'test/spec/**/*.js'
```

and it started working.
That leads me to believe there is something wrong with my application somewhere. Maybe another reference like **Modernizr**. I still have an outstanding question though. How can services that are not dependant on another service interfere?
I think it's worth noting that each service, controller, directive is in it's own file and they all follow this structure:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('sapphire.core').factory('options', service);

    function service($rootScope) {
        return {
            get: get,
            save: save
        };

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////

        function get() {
            if (typeof Modernizr == 'object' && Modernizr.localstorage) {
                var storageData = angular.fromJson(localStorage.options);
                if (storageData) {
                    return angular.fromJson(storageData);
                }
            }

            return {
                background: {
                    enabled: true,
                    enableSnow: true,
                    opacity: 0.6
                }
            };
        };

        function save(options) {
            if (typeof Modernizr == 'object' && Modernizr.localstorage) {
                localStorage.options = angular.toJson(options);
                $rootScope.$options = get();
            }
        };
    };
})();
```

I am wondering that because I wrap them in anonymous functions that execute themselves, is that what is causing this problem?

---

*** Solution ***

So in the end I found out exactly what was causing this issue. It was indeed to do with the **file** in **karma.conf.js**. I had told it to load all files and somewhere in there was something it didn't like.
After a bit of playing I finally found what it was and thought I would share it just in case someone else gets here.

The issue was routes. I am using **ui.router** and it appears that having them in your tests fail.
I changed my files section to this:

```
'src/app/app.module.js',
'src/app/**/*module.js',
'src/app/**/*constants.js',
'src/app/**/*service.js',
'src/app/**/*controller.js',
//'src/app/**/*routes.js',

'test/spec/**/*.js'
```

As you can see I have a **routes** file(s) commented out. If I bring them back in, everything fails.

Comment: This is not a AngularJS service. You created a factory which is declared as a service. Please check the service pattern of AngularJS.

Comment: I know this, but as the style guide states: Services are instantiated with the new keyword, use this for public methods and variables. Since these are so similar to factories, use a factory instead for consistency.

Comment: Is it your actual code? cause angular.module('sapphire.orders') is not module creation.

Comment: The module creation is in another file (called orders.module.js) and creates the module as such `angular.module('sapphire.orders', []);`. I should point out that his is a working existing application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your inner deliveryDatesService variable is hiding the external one.

To avoid that, you can try puting underscores around the inner service variable as per the spec on the website below:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.inject

Look for

> 'Resolving References (Underscore Wrapping)'

on that page.

Then your code would look like this:

```
beforeEach(inject(function (_deliveryDatesService_) {
         console.log(_deliveryDatesService_);
         service = _deliveryDatesService_;
         reasons = {};
         dateReasons = [{ value: 'D4' }];
}));
```

Also you need to make sure that all required files and directories are declared in karma.conf.js so that the test framework can use them.

Comment: I thought that too, did that before I made this post and it still didn't work

Comment: Well you must have others problems on top of that then, since the way the question is written, the outside service is not accessible. What does it print now in the console if you put the underscores?

Comment: Also, have you included all the appropriate .js files inside the karma.conf.js for your tests? The service declaration file has to be declared there for it to be visible.

Comment: I was thinking that. I created a test service and put it in the root of my scripts directory and made it apart of the root module. When I tried to run that test it failed because of another service (which was not a dependency, so not sure why that is). But once I fixed that, it started working. That lead me to thinking there must be something wrong in another file somewhere, even though it's not reported. So I removed my references and added only the ones I required and that worked....

Comment: I am confused. Is your problem resolved now? Did the underscore wrapping help? Did you make sure that all the files that are required are decalred in karma.conf.js?